# R: need help to speed up creating new columns in a data.frame

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, data.table

i need help to speed up a little bit of code. i have a `data.frame` "df" and would like to create new columns and fill them with given values. Here a sample code how i do it.

```
df <- as.data.frame(1:20)

a <- c(31:50)
b <- c(201:220)

df[c("A","B")] <- c(a, b)
```

now the problem is that my data is big (some million rows) and it take more time than expected, so i think there is a better way. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should try the *data.table* package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task of extending `data.frame`s (or any object) causes R to copy the whole object when you try to add a new column. Package `data.table` offers some great performance features that are added on to the `data.frame` model. It allows (among other things) to add columns in place. See the code below for a simple demo:

```
require(data.table)
a2 <- data.table(x=1:10)
a2[, y:=21:30]   ## this will create y inside a2 without copying it
summary(a2)      ## just like using a data.frame
```

The resulting object (a `data.table`) will play nice with (almost) all code that makes use of `data.frame`. It has an alternative syntax most operations, which are performed much more efficiently. It's worth spending some time looking into.

---

If you'd like to add multiple columns, then:

```
a2[, `:=`(y=21:30, z=31:40)]
```

**Edit:** @Thell has taken the time and prepared benchmarks with different methods for extending a `data.frame`. They suggest that despite the copying `data.frame` is faster. Keep this in mind as an alternative and see which one works best for your code.

Comment: It would be interesting to get @Arun's insight as to the timing variances displayed in my answer and the `tracemem` output...

Answer (score 3):

You stated you have 'some million' rows so here is an excerpt of benchmarks with 3 columns of 10 million rows...

*R 3.0.3* (on 32bit Celeron system w/ 2GB memory)

```
## Unit: microseconds
##           expr     min      lq  median      uq     max neval
##    dt.addC(dt)   35.38   56.03   64.82   67.77   185.2   100
##     df.add(df)  181.43  214.80  221.42  229.81   366.6   100
##    dt.addB(dt) 2359.54 2457.09 2513.11 2577.00  6398.0   100
##    dt.addA(dt) 2913.74 2995.64 3047.29 3125.82  6791.1   100
```

*R 3.1.0* (on 64bit Haswell i7 w/ 24 GB memory)

```
## Unit: microseconds
##           expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
##     df.add(df)     10.25     30.74     33.36     48.53     84.25   100
##    dt.addC(dt)  27120.45  27563.79  27990.22  29642.46  87637.63   100
##    dt.addB(dt)  38452.71  39018.90  46225.69  50142.46 130893.53   100
##    dt.addA(dt) 193268.78 247749.71 251380.74 256380.43 440916.17   100
```

**Note:**
The difference between `data.frame` and `data.table` on 3.1.0 can be explained by the new way that R 3.1.0 handles assignments. Arun (one of the `data.table` authors) does so in this [chat log](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16098288#16098288).

---

`df.add` ( a common base way to add columns to `dat.frame` ).

```
df$b <- b.vals
df$c <- c.vals
```

---

`dt.addA` (the common base `data.frame` method applied to `data.table`)

```
dt$b <- b.vals
dt$c <- c.vals
```

---

`dt.addB` (a common `data.table` way to add columns)

```
dt[,`:=`(b=b.vals, c=c.vals)]
```

---

`dt.addC` (another `data.table` method of setting values [from Arun] )

```
## to reduce the overhead due to `[.data.table` on small data.frames.
set(dt, j="b", value=b.vals)
set(dt, j="c", value=c.vals)
```

---

*Benchmarks for other data set sizes*

R 3.1.0 on i7 System

```
# Test @ 1,000
## Unit: microseconds
##           expr      min      lq  median      uq      max neval
##    dt.addC(dt)    6.007   10.38   11.71   12.50    20.79   100
##     df.add(df)   11.534   19.49   20.57   21.32   940.63   100
##    dt.addB(dt)  326.166  344.85  351.43  365.47  1412.86   100
##    dt.addA(dt)  798.777  850.47  867.60  888.23  1935.20   100

##            test relative
## 1    df.add(df)        1
## 4   dt.addC(dt)        1
## 3   dt.addB(dt)       35
## 2   dt.addA(dt)       87

# Test @ 10,000
## Unit: microseconds
##           expr     min      lq  median      uq     max neval
##    dt.addC(dt)   11.13   17.88   19.20   20.80   988.9   100
##     df.add(df)   10.97   20.56   22.65   24.94    41.1   100
##    dt.addB(dt)  333.17  364.15  389.87  419.08  1347.0   100
##    dt.addA(dt)  823.99  875.88  897.10 1076.90 29233.1   100

##            test relative
## 1    df.add(df)        1
## 4   dt.addC(dt)        1
## 3   dt.addB(dt)       19
## 2   dt.addA(dt)       50

# Test @ 10,000,000
## Unit: microseconds
##           expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
##     df.add(df)     10.25     30.74     33.36     48.53     84.25   100
##    dt.addC(dt)  27120.45  27563.79  27990.22  29642.46  87637.63   100
##    dt.addB(dt)  38452.71  39018.90  46225.69  50142.46 130893.53   100
##    dt.addA(dt) 193268.78 247749.71 251380.74 256380.43 440916.17   100

##            test relative
## 1    df.add(df)        1
## 4   dt.addC(dt)     1536
## 3   dt.addB(dt)     2213
## 2   dt.addA(dt)    11667
```

R 3.0.3 on Celeron System

````
# Test @ 1,000
## Unit: microseconds
##           expr     min      lq  median      uq     max neval
##    dt.addC(dt)   55.78   82.58   94.48   96.14   176.1   100
##     df.add(df)  182.65  215.36  220.10  225.03   361.6   100
##    dt.addB(dt) 2699.10 2774.61 2827.34 2894.23  3442.2   100
##    dt.addA(dt) 5259.89 6066.00 6122.37 6231.50 10265.9   100

##            test relative
## 4   dt.addC(dt)    1.000
## 1    df.add(df)    2.889
## 3   dt.addB(dt)   32.444
## 6 dfadd2dtB(dt)   69.667
## 2   dt.addA(dt)   69.889
## 5 dfadd2dtA(dt)   96.000

# Test @ 10,000
## Unit: microseconds
##           expr    min     lq median      uq   max neval
##    dt.addC(dt)  134.0  162.8  168.7   185.8  4135   100
##     df.add(df)  576.7  616.4  633.7   663.2 72749   100
##    dt.addB(dt) 2789.8 2932.6 2993.0  3054.7  6702   100
##    dt.addA(dt) 5400.6 6701.5 6819.0 10079.2 11518   100

##            test relative
## 4   dt.addC(dt)    1.000
## 1    df.add(df)    8.143
## 3   dt.addB(dt)   14.619
## 2   dt.addA(dt)   34.286
## 6 dfadd2dtB(dt)   34.381
## 5 dfadd2dtA(dt)   53.810

# Test @ 10,000,000
## Unit: milliseconds
##           expr    min     lq median     uq    max neval
##    dt.addC(dt)  121.1  146.2  147.2  161.8  303.8   100
##    dt.addB(dt)  197.7  225.4  228.0  270.2  380.7   100
##     df.add(df)  767.8  823.5  857.0  938.2 1156.9   100
##    dt.addA(dt)  709.6 1071.9 1112.6 1170.1 1343.9   100

##            test relative
## 4   dt.addC(dt)    1.000
## 3   dt.addB(dt)    1.566
## 1    df.add(df)    6.172
## 2   dt.addA(dt)    7.594
```
````

System/Session Info...

```
Intel® Core™ i7-4700MQ Processor
24 GB

## R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] rbenchmark_1.0.0     microbenchmark_1.3-0 data.table_1.9.2    
## 

## "Linux" "3.11.0-19-generic" "x86_64"


Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 2.53GHz
2 GB

## R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
## Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] rbenchmark_1.0.0     microbenchmark_1.3-0 data.table_1.9.2    
## [4] knitr_1.5           
## 

## "Linux" "3.2.0-60-generic-pae" "i686"
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this. I am new in R and just startet to think of the performance of my code, tomorrow i will spend some time on you example.

Comment: @MOMO instead of spending any length of time (outside of a quick comparison on your actual data) with this example spend some time going over R profiling and benchmarking tools (search `[r] [profiling]`). It will be time well spent.

Comment: @Thell, what's your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @Thell, for `n=1000` case, the overhead due to `[.data.table` is higher that it dominates. I've edited your post with `dt.addC which doesn't have this overhead. Maybe you could run the benchmark again?
For n= 10000000, I get dt.addB = 95ms and df.add to be 350ms. Not sure what's going on there in your case.

Comment: @Arun, updated. `dt.addC` indeed performs better, but at 10M the plain 'df' still beats it.

Comment: Just for context: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16098522#16098522

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply do the following:

```
df <- data.frame (x=1:20)
df$a <- 31:50
df$b <- 201:220
```

There's an excellent ebook called "R Fundamentals and Graphics" which will give you a solid understanding of the basics of R and its graphical features.

Comment: well, i have not tested your code, but i think it's not faster than my code. My goal was to get more speed because my data is too big. In my old code it takes around 4 minutes (for 1/10 of my data) and now a few seconds...